# Is it possible to add part of list to ByteBuilder without twice copies in dart?

Tags: dart

For example, I just want to copy the middle 4 elements of `src` to a ByteBuilder:

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main() async {
  var s1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
  var src = Uint8List.fromList(s1);
  var bb = BytesBuilder();
  var part = src.sublist(4, 8); // first copy
  bb.add(part); // second copy
  var other = bb.toBytes();
  print("$other");
}
```

Comment: If you *really* wanted, you could do: `for (var i = 4; i < 8; i += 1) { bb.addByte(src[i]); }` but I doubt that it's worth the trouble. (You don't need the `BytesBuilder` at all in your example, although I'm assuming that's an artifact of simplifying your actual code.)

Comment: This is a solution (with ugly codes ^_^). But I'll try it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `BytesBuilder` will do at least one copy. It has two modes, one where it copies when you add the bytes (but then it might need to grow its buffer occasionally), and one where it just remembers the input and does the copying when you call `toBytes` (but then changes to the original list, which happens after adding it, will apply to the result as well).

To avoid the second copy, you can use a [view on the sub-list](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.16.1/dart-typed_data/Uint8List/Uint8List.sublistView.html) instead of creating a copy.

```dart
  var part = Uint8List.sublistView(s1, 4, 8);
```

That creates a view of the slice of `s1`, but doesn't copy the elements.

If used with the late-copying `BytesBuilder`, that again means that changes to the original list will bleed through to the result.

For a relatively *short* sublist (four bytes is very much small), making a copy might be cheaper than creating a view. The copy just needs to hold the actual four bytes and a length, the view needs to refer to the original an contain two integers, which is at least three pointer-sizes of data.
For a long slice, the saving can be significant.

Comment: According to doc, the part is a new list (owns a new buffer). And I test it by code, if  I change an element in part, the corresponding element in s1 is not modified.

Comment: The doc for `Uint8List.sublistView` says that it makes a view on the original list (on it's buffer, actually), and if I test it in DartPad, the two shares a buffer., and modifications to one also modify the other.

Comment: @Irn , It's my fault. Your answer is right.